# Python - Converting a 9 digit integer into a string with the format of "xxx-xx-xxxx"

Tags: python, string, integer

I was working on some practice problems for a python course i am in and I was a little lost on one of the questions. The task seems relatively simple:

> Create a solution that accepts an integer input representing a 9-digit unformatted student identification number. Output the identification number as a string with no spaces. The solution should be in the format: 111-22-3333. So if the input is "154175430" then the expected output is "154-17-5430".

This seems pretty straightforward, however once i looked at the initial coding comments they gave us to start the program, the first line of comment read:

```
# hint: modulo (%) and floored division(//) may be used
```

This hint is what really tripped me up. I was just wondering how or why you would use a modulo or floored division if you are just converting an integer to a string? I assume it has to do with the formatting to get the "-" in between the necessary digits?

Comment: What conversion methods were you thinking of if not using modulo arithmetic?

Comment: hint on the hint: the modulo and division are not for adding the -, but for extracting eg the 17 out of 154175430

Comment: however, another option would be first to convert the integer to a string, and then use "string slicing" (google it) to split the string into 3 separate parts, and then put the dash inbetween

Answer (score 1):

Going the floor division and modulus route we can try:

```py
num = 154175430
output = str(num / 1000000) + "-" + str((num / 10000) % 100) + "-" + str(num % 10000)
print(output)  # 154-17-5430
```

We could also be lazy and use a regex replacement:

```py
num = 154175430
output = re.sub(r'(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})', r'\1-\2-\3', str(num))
print(output)  # 154-17-5430
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming an answer similar to this is wanted:

```
def int2student_id(in_val:int):
    start = in_val//1000000
    middle = in_val//10000%100
    end = in_val%10000
    return str(start) + '-' + str(middle) + '-' + str(end)

print(int2student_id(154175430))
```

Comment: I was curious if i could ask you about two things in your code. The first, is the argument in the function definition: "in_val:int". I apologize, but i'm pretty new to python. I assume that "in_val" is just a variable you named yourself and that by putting the ":int" after the name that sets the variable type as an integer. Is that correct? And secondly, how did you know what numbers to put after the floor division of each variable? Is there some formula or something about this I should read up on? Thank you for your initial reply btw.

Comment: for 'start' -> remove the last 6 digits, so floor division by 10e6.
for 'middle' ->remove the last 4 digits by floor division with 10e4 then remove all but the last 2 digits by taking the remainder with 10e2.
for 'end' -> take the remainder with 10e4 to remove all but the last 4 digits.
The ':int' in the function parameter is just a type hint for development, it does not convert the input but helps your IDE to understand the variable better